# Efficiently summing over a numpy view

Tags: python, numpy

I am using numpy's `sliding_window_view()` to generate patches from a 2D image that will independently be passed into a machine learning classifier.

```
import numpy as np
from numpy.lib.stride_tricks import sliding_window_view
# 100x100 image
img = np.random.random((100,100))
# Getting every 10x10 patch then taking every 5th in each dimension (19x19 patches)
patches = sliding_window_view(img,(10,10))[::5,::5] # view with shape (19,19,10,10)
```

I'd like to track how many times each pixel in the original image is used in a patch. When using every 5th patch, this can be calculated but in a later step I will be using a random subset of patches and will need to count for each pixel.

My solution is generating a secondary array of the same shape of zeros and adding 1 for each time a pixel is used.

```
zz = np.zeros((100,100))
zpatches = sliding_window_view(zz,(10,10))[::5,::5]
```

As `zpatches` is a view, I thought adding 1 would increment each element of `zz` each time it is used, but it appears to instead only update each element once, resulting in an array of all 1s.

```
zpatches+=1
zz == np.ones((100,100)) # True
```

I can get around this by instead explicitly looping over the two outermost axes which doesn't have overlapping data.

```
for i in range(zpatches.shape[0]):
    for j in range(zpatches.shape[1]):
        zpatches[i,j]+=1
```

But explicit python loops are not vectorized and generally have bad performance. Is there a better way to accomplish this?

Comment: As noted in the `.at` docs, `+=` is buffered, so when there are duplicates only one is changed. `add.at` takes a more iterative approach. When I've tested it, it is slower than the `+=`, but I haven't tried it on a sliding view.  What's the shape of the view?

Answer (score 2):

Use [`np.add.at`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.at.html)! Smaller example:

```
import numpy as np
from numpy.lib.stride_tricks import sliding_window_view as swv

zz = np.zeros((9, 9))
zpatches = swv(zz, (3, 3), writeable=True)[::2,::2]

np.add.at(zpatches, slice(None), 1)
```

```
>>> zz
array([[1., 1., 2., 1., 2., 1., 2., 1., 1.],
       [1., 1., 2., 1., 2., 1., 2., 1., 1.],
       [2., 2., 4., 2., 4., 2., 4., 2., 2.],
       [1., 1., 2., 1., 2., 1., 2., 1., 1.],
       [2., 2., 4., 2., 4., 2., 4., 2., 2.],
       [1., 1., 2., 1., 2., 1., 2., 1., 1.],
       [2., 2., 4., 2., 4., 2., 4., 2., 2.],
       [1., 1., 2., 1., 2., 1., 2., 1., 1.],
       [1., 1., 2., 1., 2., 1., 2., 1., 1.]])
```

Comment: Thank you! This is much more concise than the loops. Unfortunately, it is actually slightly slower in practice for my example: 

```
timeit('zz=np.zeros((100,100));\nzpatches=sliding_window_view(zz,(10,10),writeable=True);\nfor i in range(zpatches.shape[0]):\n\tfor j in range(zpatches.shape[1]):\n\t\tzwin[i,j]+=1',globals=globals(),number=100)
```

2.83 seconds

```
timeit('zz=np.zeros((100,100));\nzpatches=sliding_window_view(zz,(10,10),writeable=True);np.add.at(zpatches,slice(None),1)',globals=globals(),number=100)
```
4.73 seconds.

Maybe there isn't any speedup left.

Comment: Wow, tested it for myself and got similar results! I would have expected `np.add.at` to do better than the python loop. I don't know of a better solution, sorry :(

Comment: A final thought would be to generate your required matrix by multiplying the overlaps for the patches for each axis, instead of using the += 1 trick.